# is calling values().size() on a Map linear or constant

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

In java, what is the time complexity of a HashMap `getValues().size()`? is it linear or is it constant? I image constant, but I am not sure. how about `getValues().get(n)`

Comment: Note that this is implementation-dependent; although it's constant in the Oracle JRE (and probably all of them), there's no requirement for it on `Map` or even on `HashMap` specifically. You can [take a look at the code in question yourself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's constant, and it's exactly equivalent to just calling `Map.size()` in the first place.

Comment: There's no such method.  `HashMap` has a `values()` method, not `getValues()`, and it returns a `Collection`, which doesn't provide a `get(int)` method.

Comment: wow you are very exact. Cool. yes, that's what I meant. Once I get the collection if I cast it to a List, then what happens if I get get(n)?

Comment: If you cast it to a `List`, you'll get a `ClassCastException`, because it's not a `List`.  If you copy it into a `List`, then you'll get the performance for whatever `List` implementation you copied it into.

Comment: @CoteMounyo if you look at the source code for `HashMap` you will find that `values()` is actually an anonymous class extending `AbstractCollection`. Casting to `List` won't do anything good.

Comment: The question is about ``Map``, not ``HashMap``.  The answer depends on the underlying implementation.  It could be a distributed map that queries data on other computers, a concurrent map with its own performance characteristics, or a synchronized map which might be linear but could be blocked by another thread manipulating the map (meaning that it might be a linear implementation but that says nothing about how long it a call to compute the size will take).

Comment: @TimBoudreau: The question title says `Map`, the question text says `HashMap`, which I'll take as being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int size() {
  return size;
}
```

This is the source code. Constant time.

The return value of [Map#values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) is of type `Collection`, which does not support the `get(n)` operation. In order to get the `n`th element, you might have to iterate through the collection, which is linear time.